# Installing Maldicore PHP Admin

Tags: php, cakephp

I am very new to Cake PHP - I have completed a few tutorials so my knowledge is very limited at the moment.

I am attempting to install and use the Maldicore Admin Dashboard.

https://github.com/Maldicore/Admin

After successfully installing the plugin - I am now totally confused around how to link certain tables from my database into the admin dashboard.

For the purposes of this scenario, how would I create menu options for the following tables:

- Posts
- Groups
- Users

The installation guide is a bit fuzzy on the next steps to link content from your database to the Plugin.

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Maldicore admin panel requires for you to have existing Models in your cakephp, then it will automatically create the corresponding menu and administrating options in the admin panel.

For example,
app/Model/Post.php :

```
class Post extends extends AppModel {}
```

Admin panel should then automatically display the menu option for Post.

Hope this answers